# Trigger fancybox when query string is not null in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I have video page where i show list of video and on click i play video in fancybox.

If user shares URL then for example `http://www.website.com/videos/?v=OL0n7h9qsUI` then i pass video ID as parameter and i want to open fancy box by default and play the same video  if it is shared url.

Below is the code that i am working on i tried to call trigger function but it fails to show. May be i am doing something wrong

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

//Example URL = http://www.website.com/videos/?v=OL0n7h9qsUI

    var vid = getParameterByName('v');

    alert("VID : " + vid);

    if (vid=="")
    {
        $(".video-fancybox").click(function () {
            // first, get the value from the alt attribute
            var newTitle = $(this).find("img").attr("alt"); // Get alt from image
            $.fancybox({
                'padding': 0,
                'autoScale': false,
                'transitionIn': 'none',
                'transitionOut': 'none',
                //'title': this.title, // we will replace this line
                'title': newTitle,  //<--- this will do the trick
                'width': 680,
                'height': 495,
                //'href': this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
                'href': 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + vid,
                'type': 'swf',
                'swf': { 'wmode': 'transparent', 'allowfullscreen': 'true' }

            });
            // alert(this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Views.aspx?youtubeVideoID=" + this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            });
            return false;
        });
```

I am using old fancybox file `jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js`

UPDATE:

I tried to open fancybox on load, with below script fancybox open but doesnt show any video.

```
$.fancybox({
    'padding': 0,
    'autoScale': false,
    'transitionIn': 'none',
    'transitionOut': 'none',
    //'title': this.title, // we will replace this line
    //'title': newTitle,  //<--- this will do the trick
    'width': 680,
    'height': 495,
    //'href': this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
    'href': 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + vid,
    'type': 'swf',
    'swf': { 'wmode': 'transparent', 'allowfullscreen': 'true' }
});
```

Comment: Do you get any console error?

Comment: I think you just need `$(".video-fancybox").trigger('click')`, As of now you are just bind the click handler

Comment: Where do you execute this body??? You need to wrap this inside a document ready function or inside a function which fire when user click on somethig

Comment: @Satpal, you mean `$(".video-fancybox").trigger('click', function(){......});

Comment: @NishanSenevirathna, how will i pass the vidoe url to function afte i trigger

Comment: @Learning, I mean `$(".video-fancybox").click(function () { //your existing code }).trigger('click')`

Comment: I tried this it doesnt work